# Javascript count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have function which needs to execute a certain number of times based on the input of the user

```
(e.g)
 var count=  $('#count').val();//user defined value
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                GenerateData();

                  }
 function GenerateData() {
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: url, // Location of the service
        data: "{}", //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
        dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
        processdata: true, //True or False
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails

    });
 }
   function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
  alert("Data generated successfully");
 }
```

But after the Ajax function is executed the count variable is reset to null. Hence the program executes only once irrespective of the input. Im stuck here.. so any help is appreciated

Comment: You've not shown the crucial bit of code - which is how you execute this in the first place.

Comment: when user clicks start this function begins execution...the generate data function should ideally be executed based on the count value entered by user

Comment: do you see that many requests going out? maybe you are fighting asyncronous requests, or your server isn't responding with the right data. you should look into the requests itselves, if they contain your wanted result

Comment: Perhaps instead of running `count` AJAX requests, you should pass `count` in the `data` and perform only one AJAX request to get multiple results at once.

Comment: try to use console.log instead of alert window and you will see that it is executed i times.

Comment: @Blazemonger thought of that... but program needs to send data to the ajax server based on count... ajax function executes only once

Comment: @lombausch I don't want to see no. of times its executed...just want it to execute for a specified no. of times

Comment: `when user clicks start this function begins execution` - show this function.

Comment: <input type="button" value="start" onclick="generation();">  and the code block is within the function generation();

Comment: @RohitRanjit isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @RohitRanjit, can you please provide your count id html part. Is it span tag or anything else?

Comment: @lombausch ill rephrase that... in my fn. I get random values and pass it through ajax. At the receiving end theres a function which only accepts the values sent and programs accordingly. I cant use count in the receiving end coz it needs values from sender to compute

Comment: @RGS its in <div><input type="button" value="start" onclick="generation();"> </div>

Comment: @RohitRanjit, I bet your loop executes i times. It just doesn't let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var count=  $('#count').val();//user defined value
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     GenerateData(i);
 }

 function GenerateData(i) {
     $.ajax({

        type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: url, // Location of the service
        async: false, // here you make the call synchronous, which means that you are waiting for       respone
        cache: false,
        data: "{}", //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
        dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
        processdata: true, //True or False
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails

    });
 }
```